# Casting from size_t to char and around

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I'm making the transition from C to C++11 now and I try to learn more about casting.
At the end of this question you see a small program which asked a number as input and then shows it as number and as character. Then it is cast to a char, and after that I cast it back to a size_t.

When I give 200 as input, the first cout prints 200, but the second cout prints 18446744073709551560. 
How do I made it to print 200 again? Do I use the wrong cast? I have already tried different cast as dynamic and reintepret.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){  
  size_t value;

  cout << "Give a number between 32 and 255: ";
  cin >> value;

  cout << "unsigned value: " << value << ", as character: `" << static_cast<char>(value) << "\'\n";

  char ch = static_cast<char>(value);
  cout << "unsigned value: " << static_cast<size_t>(ch) << ", as character: `"  << ch << "\'\n";
}
```

Comment: Converting between `size_t` and `char` is perfectly legal, but I can't think of a case where you'd actually want to do it in real life.

Comment: True, in real life is isn't necessary (I guess?). However, I try to get a better understanding of casting and the different types in C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`size_t` is unsigned, plain `char`'s signed-ness is implementation-defined.

Casting `200` to a *signed* char will yield a negative result as 200 is larger than `CHAR_MAX` which is `127` for the most common situation, an 8-bit char.  (Advanced note - this conversion is also *implementation-defined* but for all practical purposes you can assume a negative result; in fact usually `-56`).

Casting *that* negative value back to an unsigned (but wider) integer type will yield a rather large value, because unsigned arithmetic wraps around.

You might cast the value to an `unsigned char` first (yielding the expected *small* positive value), *then* cast that the wider unsigned type.

Most compilers have a switch that lets you toggle plain `char` over to `unsigned` so you could experiment with that. When you come to write portable code, try to write code that will work correctly in both cases!

Comment: Re. the update: it makes no difference whether there is 1's complement, signed-magnitude etc. etc.  C++ arithmetic works in terms of values. It sounds like you were distracted by some incorrect comments (which have now been deleted!)